# IDeserializationCallback vs OnDeserializedAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, ideserializationcallback

As far as I understand, the IDeserializationCallback interface and the OnDeserialized event can both be used when an object needs to perform some task after being deserialized.

IDeserializationCallback:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo : IDeserializationCallback
{
    public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
         // initialize unserialized fields etc.
    }
}
```

OnDeserialized event:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
         // initialize unserialized fields etc.
    }
}
```

Are there any specific pros/cons or scenarios where you would choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wondered the same thing. As far as pros/cons go, I can only reason that the interface has an advantage in that it forces you to implement the correct method signature where-as the attribute version will happily let you compile your class regardless of what your method signature looks like.

Comment: Good point. That is a quite nice advantage of using the IDeserializationCallback interface.

Comment: Actually this is not the right answer - look at Val's answer and follow the link there.

Answer (score 11):

Those two serve different purposes and cannot be used interchangeably. In most of the cases you probably will be better served by the interface.

Look here for some explanation:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/311b2b57-6b0a-49ed-aa96-84f69d51da0f

Answer (score 8):

Darren Headrick's post from above link (for completeness) :

DeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization "Runs when the entire object graph has been deserialized." ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.ondeserialization.aspx)).

The OnDeserialized event however "Use the OnDeserializedAttribute when you need to fix values on a deserialized object after it has been deserialized and before the graph is returned. This attribute can be used instead of the IDeserializationCallback interface." ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx)).

Since the OnDeserialized attribute can be used to modify the object graph, it gets called before OnDeserialization (which signifies the Object graph is in its final state).